# Field update Onclick Javascript not showing on record

Tags: apex, javascript, ajax

I am trying to update a field on a record using an OnClick Javascript button. It seems to be updating the record but when I refresh the page nothing shows. What am I doing wrong?

Below is my code:

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js")}

var jobRequisition = new sforce.SObject("Job_Requisition__c");
jobRequisition.Id = "{!Job_Requisition__c.Id}";
jobRequisition.requisition__c = 'Something';

var result = sforce.connection.update([jobRequisition]);
window.location.reload();
```

When I check the result I get this error:

```
{errors:{fields:'Id', message:'Record ID: id value of incorrect type: 559e1e161ef6752dff2ff0f1', statusCode:'MALFORMED_ID', }, id:null, success:'false', }
```

I have a field called id__c with the "559e1e161ef6752dff2ff0f1" value, but I specified `jobRequisition.Id`in the above code so I do not understand why it is referencing that. I believe this should be the salesforce Id not my custom field

Comment: Have you checked the `result` for success?

Comment: I have, please take a look at the update

Comment: What is the value of `{!Job_Requisition__c.Id}` on line three?

Comment: I couldn't see any issues, it should work. Please check if this same code is there in your Org.

Comment: @Rob I get "undefined" when I try display the value of the Id field in an alert.

Comment: Hi Nelson, if you view the HTML source of your page, what does the line `jobRequisition.Id = "{!Job_Requisition__c.Id}";` look like?

Comment: @NelsonChisoko Try using TEXT function like "{!TEXT(Job_Requisition__c.Id)}"

Comment: @Rob I am not using a visualforce page. I am using a standard page just implementing the javascript updated based on the button

Comment: @NelsonChisoko what do you mean by just standard page? Are you using <apex:page or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of Salesforce Ajax toolkit implementation. I am creating an Account then updating it and again retrieving the updated account. You can see all the details in the browser console.

It is a standalone page you can check and compare with your code.

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
    </script>
    <script src="../../soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //create an account
        var account = new sforce.SObject("Account");
        account.Name = "myName";
        result = sforce.connection.create([account]);

        //update that account
        account.id = result[0].id;
        account.Phone = "1234567890";
        result = sforce.connection.update([account]);
        console.log("result" +result);

        //Retrieving the account
        var qRresult;
        if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {
          console.log("account with id " + result[0].id + " updated");
          qRresult = sforce.connection.retrieve("Name,Phone", "Account", [result[0].id]);
          console.log("result" +qRresult);
          console.log("result" +qRresult[0].Phone);
        } else {
          console.log("failed to update account " + result[0]);
        }   
    </script>    
</apex:page>
```

Comment: is the account.id the salesforce Id or is it a custom field you named id (id__c)

Comment: account.id the salesforce Id Id not the custom Id.